# Check if keyword exists in any capacity in string

Tags: python

```
urgency = ["asap", "now", "quickly"]
test = 'the patientneeds help/asap'

if any(elem in test.split() for elem in urgency):
    print('Element Found')
```

When I run this, I was expecting the keyword "asap" to be found, but unfortunately, this seems to only do exact matches.

Comment: `.split()` is redundant.

Comment: If you have a string `"know"`, would you consider that as having found `"now"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a regex, and add the condition that you want a word boundary `\b` at the start and end of each of your searched words:

```
import re


def is_urgent(sentence):
    urgency = ["asap", "now", "quickly"]
    return any(re.search(r'\b' + urgent_word + r'\b', sentence) for urgent_word in urgency)

tests = ['the patient needs help/asap', 'he needs help asap', 'wait until snowfall']

for test in tests:
    if is_urgent(test):
        print('URGENT:', test)
    else:
        print('Not urgent:', test)
```

Output:

```
URGENT: the patient needs help/asap
URGENT: he needs help asap
Not urgent: wait until snowfall
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want specific words and want to avoid triggers like `snowfall` and `know` for example, you can try this:

```py
import re

urgency = ["asap", "now", "quickly"]
test = 'the patientneeds help/asap'

words = set(re.split(r"\W+", test))

if any(elem in words for elem in urgency):
    print('Element Found')
```

There doesn't seem like there's any easy solution for splitting "patientneeds", (words concatenated with no character delimiter), but this provides actually a pretty robust mechanism for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `split()`. But `in` will become `True` for `now` in `know`.

```
urgency = ["asap", "now", "quickly"]
test = 'the patientneeds help/asap'

if any(elem in test for elem in urgency):
    print('Element Found')
```

Comment: This would print "Element Found" with `test = "Wait until snowfall!"`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I actually think OP needs to clarify, maybe he wants it to be triggered with that input

Comment: Well, maybe, but as much as I can feel a sense of urgency in everything he put in the `urgency` list, I fail to feel it in my suggested test, so I really doubt it.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yeah...I have included it in my answer